# My Sql query is slow if values falls outside index max value

Tags: mysql, indexing

I faced a peculiar issue with mysql last night. So i have table that has four columns `( A text, B text, C text , D number)` . i created D as my `index( B-Tree Mysql Index with innodb engine)`.

Suppose after inserting the data in the table : D has max value of 100 and min Value of 0;

While Querying on field D:

- `where D = 25` . The query executes in immediately
- `where D = 125` (i.e value does not exist in table) . The query executes in ages

As I understand indexing is smart enough to recognize that this value is contained in the table and should execute very quickly as the other. I looked up at the explain query plan, it showed 50% table scan on key 'field D'. I not able to understand why is taking so much time to execute the second query?

My table has roughly 20 million rows. 

PS: I have used number numbers just to explain.

Thank you

Comment: Show both queries fully.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a try with `not exists` like the following query?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  null 
        FROM    mytable b
        WHERE   a.id = b.id
        AND b.id = 125
        );
```